# Identify which element id or class was clicked using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Suppose I have

```
<body>
 <div id="stuff">
  <div id="cat">a</div>
  <div id="dog">b</div>
  <div id="elephant">c</div>
  <div id="rabbit">d</div>
  <div id="frog">e</div>  
 </div>
</body>​
```

So far the closet I could get was with JS,

```
document.getElement('body').onclick = function(e){
    alert(e.target.innerHTML);
}​
```

Which prints out the contents of the div when I want the literal div id like 'cat' or 'dog' not 'a' or 'b'. Also I am trying to accomplish this using jQuery, am I heading in the right direction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to include [**jQuery**](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aHow_jQuery_Works) js file in order to use jQuery methods.

With jQuery

```
$('body').click(function(e){
    alert(e.target.innerHTML);
    alert(e.target.id)
    alert($(e.target).attr('id'));
}​);
```

With Javascript

```
document.getElement('body').onclick = function(e){
    alert(e.target.innerHTML);
    alert(e.target.id)
}​
```

Sample html page using JQuery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>jQuery demo</title>
 </head>
 <body>
   <a href="http://jquery.com/">jQuery</a>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
     document.getElement('body').onclick = function(e){
        alert(e.target.innerHTML);
        alert(e.target.id)
     }​
   </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

http://jsbin.com/ohotuv/1/edit

```
document.getElementById('stuff').onclick = function( e ){
    alert( e.target.id );
};
```

jQ way:

```
$('#stuff').click(function( e ){
    alert( e.target.id );
});
```

If it has not an **ID**, but has a **CLASS** (and you want it!) you can do:

http://jsbin.com/ohotuv/3/edit - (where "elephant" is a class)

```
$('#stuff').click(function( e ){
    var name = e.target.id || e.target.className;
    alert(name);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using pure `javascript` you may need to make it cross browser compatible.

```
window.onload=function(){
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].onclick = function(e){
        e = e ? e : window.event;
        var source = e.target || e.srcElement;
        alert(source.id);
    }
}
```

Comment: just came back to give you a little heads-Up. nice answer. `+`

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend reading up on [**jQuery.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

In your example I'd recommend:

```
$("body").on("click", function(event){
  alert($(this).id);
});
```

Although it's highly recommended to reduce the scope what what elements you're looking for the click event.  For example:

```
$("#stuff").on("click", "div", function(event){
  alert($(this).id);
});
```

Which would only handle ANY div element inside the html tag with the id of stuff.  Reducing the context of handling events can help with encapsulation and debugging problems.